# problems with HSD.test

Tags: anova, dataset, tukey-hsd-test

I would like to do a HSD.test. I have found an example of this and this example is working fine. This is the example:

```
library(agricolae)
data(sweetpotato)
model<-aov(yield~virus, data=sweetpotato)
out <- HSD.test(model,"virus", group=TRUE,console=TRUE,
            main="Yield of sweetpotato\nDealt with different virus")
```

And the output:

```
Study: Yield of sweetpotato
Dealt with different virus

HSD Test for yield 

Mean Square Error:  22.48917 

virus,  means

yield      std r  Min  Max
cc 24.40000 3.609709 3 21.7 28.5
fc 12.86667 2.159475 3 10.6 14.9
ff 36.33333 7.333030 3 28.0 41.8
oo 36.90000 4.300000 3 32.1 40.4

alpha: 0.05 ; Df Error: 8 
Critical Value of Studentized Range: 4.52881 

Honestly Significant Difference: 12.39967 

Means with the same letter are not significantly different.

Groups, Treatments and means
a    oo      36.9 
ab   ff      36.33 
bc   cc      24.4 
c    fc      12.87
```

> however, with my script, it does not work:

```
library(agricolae)
data(ddrought)
model<-aov(ddrought$`wet tubers`~ddrought$Name)
summary(model)
out<-HSD.test(do.aov, ddrought$Name, group=TRUE, console=TRUE, main="meh")
```

It seems to go wrong at data(ddrought) because there I get the following warning:

```
> library(agricolae)
> data(ddrought)
Warning message:
In data(ddrought) : data set ‘ddrought’ not found
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not statistics and off topic.